# Load from file Error c#

Tags: c#

I am doing a mathematics quiz and I successfully saved both my question and answer in a different file. Now I am trying to load my questions from my file in a label. I will load each line of the file as a different question.

This is how I save my file:

```
//checking if question or answer textbox are empty. If they are not then the question is saved

if (txtquestion.Text != "" & txtanswer.Text != "") {
  //saves the question in the questions text
  using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Questions.txt", true)) {
    file.WriteLine(txtquestion.Text);
  }
  //saves the answer in the answers text
  using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Answers.txt", true)) {
    file.WriteLine(txtanswer.Text);
  }
  MessageBox.Show("Question and Answer has been succesfully added in the Quiz!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
  //cleaning the textboxes for a new question and answer
  txtanswer.Text = "";
  txtquestion.Text = "";
} else if (txtquestion.Text == "")
//checks if the question textbox is empty and shows the corresponding message
  else if (txtquestion.Text == "")
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a question", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  else  //checks if the answer textbox is empty and shows the corresponding message
    if (txtanswer.Text == "")
      MessageBox.Show("Please enter an answer", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

This is how I am trying to load the question:

```
private void frmquestion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string line;
  string[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Questions.txt");
  line = file.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

The error I get is:

> 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ReadLine' and no extension method 'ReadLine' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Remember, @Antreas; `Array`s allow you to store information (and also access it, manipulate it, etc), while the `System.IO.File` class enables you to read information from a file into an `Array`, or write the contents of an array to a file. Have a look at these links. `Array`s: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx - `System.IO.File` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Comment: That was a helpful link thanks

Answer (score 3):

[**`File.ReadAllLines`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) method reads all lines of the file into a string array. So you have array of strings but you name it as `file`, Use meaningful names for variables will increase readability of the code.

```
 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Questions.txt");
```

Now  if you need to print each line you have to loop though the string array.

```
foreach(var line in lines)
   Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Few more things not related to your questions but about your coding

```
if (txtquestion.Text != "" & txtanswer.Text != "") {
```

Here you can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` method to check empty strings like below

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtquestion.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtanswer.Text)) {
```

Note that you need to use `&&` for AND operator

Answer (score 1):

Each element in the `file` array is a line from your file.

So you should change this code:

```
line = file.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(line);
```

To this:

```
foreach(string line in file) {
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

This will go through each line and print it out to the console.

Comment: Thanks !After that i made my label change its text and get it from line. it works :)